# Xubuntu Won't boot after installation

Tags: boot, xubuntu

After making a bootable usb for Xubuntu I install it on my machine then reboot the machine without the usb in using lagacy mode. It brings up a screen saying no bootable devices found. I have been trying to resolve this for 2 days.

Comment: did you install grub to the MBR (/sda)

Comment: I used boot tool I it still didn't help

Comment: are you booting legacy mode with an MBR disk? or gpt disk?

Comment: What is a MBR disk and gdp.

Comment: two different methodes for partitioning one for legacy and one for UEFI

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's Mbr

Comment: be sure you are booting legacy mode

Comment: I tried booting in legacy and UEFI but it did not work.

Comment: Boot a live session, install and run Boot Repair (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair 2nd option). Do NOT apply any fix for the moment. Instead, generate a report, then [edit] your question and include it so we can see what's happening. Also please post your hardware specs, make/model, as some notebooks/motherboards may require additional steps or workarounds for some "broken" UEFIs and yes, it may not be possible to install in Legacy mode (why you would want that is beyond my understanding; absolutely NO reason for that unless when dual booting with an OS that support Legacy only)